# java object array size

Tags: java, arrays, object

When calculate memory size of an object array, following code gives **"used 24 bytes"** as expected, which, as far as I know, consists of:

`4bytes(element pointer)+16bytes(object header)+4bytes(element space) = 24bytes`

```
// with JVM argument -XX:-UseTLAB
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long size = memoryUsed();
    Object[] o = new Object[]{1};
    //Object[] o = new Object[]{1L};
    size = memoryUsed() - size;
    System.out.printf("used %,d bytes%n", size);
    //Output: used 24 bytes
}

public static long memoryUsed() {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}
```

But when element type changed to Long (1L), the result is confusing, most of the time it's **"used 9,264 bytes"**, anyone can help enlighten me? what is the difference in memory allocation between this two element type?

```
// with JVM argument -XX:-UseTLAB
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long size = memoryUsed();
    //Object[] o = new Object[]{1};
    Object[] o = new Object[]{1L};
    size = memoryUsed() - size;
    System.out.printf("used %,d bytes%n", size);
    //Output: used 9,264 bytes
}
```

Comment: Probably to create the second array the JVM has to load additional classes (like `Long` and it's internal class `Long.LongCache`) which consume more memory than you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Comment: you could btw accept the answer here if it answered your question... see how its done here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to calculate an object size in general, as there is a specialized tool for that, called [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/).

It's not entirely correct how you think about it. The total size of that object is going to be `40 bytes`. Let's see where this space is coming from:

```
12 bytes headers (8 bytes + 4 bytes, since there are two headers)
```

You thought it's `16 bytes` ( 8 + 8 ), but there is the `compressed oops` option that is on by default. You can disable it via `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` and indeed in this case the size of the headers is going to be `16 bytes`.

```
4 bytes size of the array (arrays have an int size that is stored in headers)
4 bytes is the reference size of the Integer (1)
4 bytes alignment (since objects are 8 bytes aligned - this is the trick behind CompressedOops btw)
```

So far you have `24 bytes` for the array.

Now, you store an Integer inside it, that is an Object too, thus:

```
12 bytes headers
4 bytes for the actual int value inside Integer
```

Thus the total size is `40 bytes`.

Comment: Could it be that the Integer stored in this array is its primitive type, so it saves the extra 16bytes object header

Comment: @鄭无爲 well you declared it as an `Object` so it will be `Integer`; if you want to save that space you need declare it as `int[]`