# Passing variable number of parameters from calling method

Tags: java

Assuming we have a method that receives at least one parameter and potentially 0 or more parameters of the same type:

```
public void method(T p1, T... otherPs)
```

And that we have a method that calls it that looks like this:

```
public void callingMethod(T... params)
```

that we know has at least one parameter.

Is it possible to call `method` from `callingMethod` to look something like this?

```
public void callingMethod(T... params){
    [...]
    method(params[0], restOfParams);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: not really, you would need to use `Arrays::copyOfRange` looks like in this case

Comment: You can change signature of the method to accept second parameter as a list of Type. And use that list to retrieve values. List can hold values 0...n .

Comment: the signature of the 'method' cannot be changed, only the 'callingMethod'. Number of parameters is not known, it is built during runtime, so the only thing I know is that there will be at least one. 
Also, creating new array would potentially cause issues as to resource management.
Also#2: creating new method on top is not permitted, due to the same reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that is possible and pretty easy.
The only overhead is the creation of another array.
See Eugene [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747606/java-object-array-size/47749301#47749301) to understand the memory consumption.

---

```
public void callingMethod(T... params){
    ...
    method(params[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length));
    ...
}
```

---

A bit off topic, but I just run JOL, as suggested, and here is the output for an empty references' array

```
final String[] array = new String[0];
```

---

```
# Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
# Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
# Using compressed klass with 0x0000000800000000 base address and 0-bit shift.
# Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
# Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
# Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

[Ljava.lang.String;@7ea37dbfd object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                PATH                           VALUE
        71695b2d0         16 [Ljava.lang.String;                                []
```

For an array with a single, `null`, element

```
final String array = new String[1];
```

---

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@7ea37dbfd object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                PATH                           VALUE
        71692a7a8         24 [Ljava.lang.String;                                [null]
```

For an array containing a single, non-`null`, element

```
final String array = new String[1];
array[0] = new String("");
```

---

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@7ea37dbfd object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE                PATH                           VALUE
        707612b68         16 [B                  [0].value                      []
        707612b78    1577856 (something else)    (somewhere else)               (something else)
        707793ef8         24 [Ljava.lang.String;                                [(object)]
        707793f10         24 java.lang.String    [0]                            (object)
```

Comment: _only_ another array reference? that is created a whole new array.

Comment: @Eugene if the elements are references, their pointers are simply copied.

Comment: an array has at least two headers + the size, and those references have at least `12 bytes` each too

Comment: that is a wrong calculation. I recommend you use `jol` for this to know exactly what it is - or simply don't put it in the answer if you are not sure or guess (it's not related to the question anyway)

Comment: I'll give `jol` a try, but I'm pretty sure the calculation is right.

Comment: at least the fact that you say that array elements references are `8 bytes` *is* wrong. each object has two headers, either they have `12` or `16` bytes total; then `array reference` is usually `12` bytes too with compressed OOP; then the padding is also at least miss-placed in your answer. read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47749301/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene thanks, that is interesting, I removed the bytes counts. Will eventually link your answer.

Comment: @Eugene could you check out the results I got from JOL?

Comment: @Eugene it seems the array size per-se is 16 bytes, plus 8 per reference to a `String`.

Comment: sorry, have no time to deal with this now - did you check the JOL samples? there are thins that are explained there IIRC

Comment: @Eugene yes, that's straight from the samples. No worries

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in a least a couple of ways.

Because varargs in Java is syntactic sugar around passing in an array, yu can create an array with the rest of the params (perhaps using [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,int,int))) and pass that in as the second argument:

```
method(params[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length));
```

The other way is via reflection, but you don't need that here.

Comment: thanks for the input, I'm having issues with 2 arrays in resources, so reflection is the LAST thing I need in this one :)

Comment: @CosminO - :-) And whenever you don't need it (and you don't here), ...

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question, but not necessary that there is at least one parameter in varargs.

Additionally, you can check params.length != 0

And then call 
    method(params[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length));

Comment: don't just copy someone's answer, it's rude.

Comment: @Cosmino the text is copied not the answer. It's too narrow thinking